# Optimal layout of 2D array with least memory access time

Tags: memory, multidimensional-array

Let us say I have a 2D array that I can read from a file

```
1 2 3 4   
5 6 7 8  
9 10 11 12  
13 14 15 16
```

I am looking to store them as 1D array arr[16].
I am aware of row wise and column wise storage.
This messes up the structure of the array. Say I would like to convolve this with a 2X2 filter. Then at conv(1,1), I would be accessing memory at position 1,2,5,6.
 Instead, can I optimize the storage of the data in a pattern such that the elements 1,2,5,6 are stored next to each other rather than being located far away ?
 This reduces memory latency issue.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your processor, but supposing you have a typical Intel cache line size of 64 bytes, then picking square subregions that are each 64 bytes in size feels like a smart move.

If your individual elements are a byte each then 8x8 subtiles makes sense. So, e.g.

```
#define index(x, y) (x&7) | ((y&7) << 3) | \
    ((x&~7) << 6) | ((y&~7) ... shifted and/or multiplied as per size of x)
```

So in each full tile:

- in 49 of every 64 cases all data is going to be within the same cache line;
- in a further 14 it's going to lie across two cache lines; and
- in one case in 64 is it going to need four.

So that's an average of 1.265625 cache lines touched per output pixel, versus 2.03125 in the naive case.

Comment: If I am not aware of the filter size, how may I proceed ?I am thinking of optimizing the layout itself so that data in the matrix that are close to one another are close in memory as well. I was wondering if techniques like the Hilbert curve layout might be used.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what I was looking for. I was looking for what is called Morten ordering of an array that has shown to reduce memory access time. One another method would be to use the hilbert curve method which is shown to be more effective than the morten ordering method.

I am attaching a link to an article explaining this

https://insidehpc.com/2015/10/morton-ordering/